# CitusDB append distribution on non-numeric column

Tags: postgresql, citus

I am reading the CitusDB documentation here: https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v6.1/reference/append.html and I understand the mechanics of how append distribution works. However, I would like to know if the append distribution would work on non-numeric columns too. For example:

```
create_distributed_table('distributed_table', 'non_numeric_col', 'append');
```

where the **non_numeric_col** could have values in the form of **alphabet_number** "A_61", "B_355" etc.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, assuming you are going to use `TEXT` datatype for your partition column. Technically, Citus append partitioning method works with column types having `min()` and `max()` functions defined.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful!